# java.lang.SecurityException: get package info: Neither user 1010004 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: java, android, security, exception

My app logs remote crashes thanks to ACRA and today I got this one :

```
STACK_TRACE java.lang.SecurityException: get package info: Neither user 1010004 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard(IInputMethodManager.java:1289)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isCurrentInputMethodAsSamsungKeyboard(InputMethodManager.java:2526)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.updateSuggestions(Editor.java:3004)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2873)
at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1995)
at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1830)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I have no idea where does this come from! Never saw this one during development and I can't find any relevant information on the web. If anyone can help me :)

Thanks

Edit: 
If it can be relevant, here's my permissions in my manifest.xlm:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

you need to add the permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
```